# find a basis for $R^4$ given the vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

i need help with this excercise..

find a basis for $R^4$ given the vectors.

$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}\quad \text{and}\quad \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2}  \end{pmatrix}$$

What method do I follow to find the other two vectors?

Comment: For instance, Gram Schmidt algorithm.

Comment: to find a basis, you can also simplify the two starting vectors multipling by a constant or combining them, e.g. their are equivalent to (1,0,1,0) and (-1,1,-1,1)

Comment: You could guess any two other vectors and be right almost surely.

Comment: Try `\Bbb{R}` for $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

a easy way is to search vectors orthogonal to each of the selected vectors for the basis

e.g. (0,1,0,1) is orthogonal to both of them

Answer (score 1):

**Clearly,** **$v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent**, then you can add a new vector $v_3$ that is not in the span of

$$v_1=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}\quad \text{and}\quad v_2=\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2}  \end{pmatrix}$$

Finally add a 4th vector $v_4$ that is not an element in the span of $v_1,v_2,v_3$.